# navigator.app.exitApp(); doesn't work when use cordova dialogs plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins, dialog, exit, confirm

I want to use navigator.app.exitApp(); to exit from my cordova app with a dialog box.i also installed cordova dialogs plugin.

This is my code:

```
<script>
    function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
alert('You selected button' + buttonIndex);
}


navigator.notification.confirm(
'Do you want to exit app?', // message
 onConfirm,            // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
'Exit',           // title
['Yes','No']     // buttonLabels
);


     onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
if (buttonIndex==2){
navigator.app.exitApp();
}
}
</script>


<button onclick="onConfirm(); return false;">Exit</button>
```

But it doesn't work.

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Mohsen Alk Try this is already checked and it is working

```
<input type="button" value="exit" id="exit" onclick="payrent();" />

function payrent() {
    navigator.notification.confirm(
        'You are about to leave this app and open your default web browser. Continue?',
        payrent1, // <-- no brackets
        'Leave App?',
        ['Ok', 'Cancel']
    );
}

function payrent1(buttonIndex) {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
}
```